# Normal Modes of a Suspended Rod with Strings of Fixed Lengths

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, normal-modes

> A thin uniform rod of length $ 2b $  is suspended by two vertical light strings, both of
>   fixed length $ l $ , fastened to the ceiling. Assuming only small displacements from equilibrium, find the Lagrangian of the system and the normal frequencies. Find and describe the normal modes.

The problem above is from the book Classical Mechanics by Taylor. The difficulty of the problem lies in choosing the three coordinates, that uniquely describe the position of the rod and the computation of the various lengths become possible.

Clearly, one set of locii is the two spheres of length $ l $ centered at the two ends of strings. However, whatever choice of three coordinates I make, I always get two possible solutions. The reason is that whenever we fix a certain cooridnate system, we describe a construction problem, which eventually involves a line, a plane or another sphere interesting with our two spheres. Unless I can choose a coordinates that "uniquely" describe the configuration, I cannot, for instance, calculate the height or other lengths     needed to write the potential energy.

P.S. The hint from the book is

> A possible choice of generalized coordinates would be $ x $ , the longitudinal displacement of the rod, and $  y _  { 1 } $ and  $ y_{2} $  , the sideways displacements of the rod's two ends. You'll need to find how high the two ends
>   are above their equilibrium height and what angle the rod has turned through.

This, however, doesn't seem to help, as the problem again turns out to be a complicated locii problem. We get two parallel circles that are a distance of $ y_{1}  + y_{2} $ in the space, and we need to joint two points on these two circles such that the resulting line passes through another line (which is described by the longitudinal condition of $ x $   coordinate).   This in general, does not have a unique solution. How do I get around this difficulty.

EDIT: I am not asking a full solution to this problem. I am asking if anyone can describe the geometry of the problem by an ingenious choice of coordinates, or if possible, explain what are the cooridnates $ y_{1}   $ and $ y_{2} $ as suggested by Taylor. If these are the "horizontal" distances from the intitial plane of the system, then, we run into the difficulties mentioned above.